# Discontinuities of $f(x)=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\{nx\}}{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\{nx\}}{n^2}$ where $\{\}$ is fractional part. Find all discontinuities of function $f(x)$.

I think that $f(x)$ is discontinuous at every rational point.

Can anyone show how to prove strictly that $f$ for example is discontinuous at $0$ or $1/2$?

Comment: You are correct about the set of discontinuities being $\mathbb{Q}$. The idea is to look at the partial sum sequence of $f$, i.e., $f_n(x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\{kx\}}{k^2}$. The jump discontinuity at a rational point of $f_n$ will tend to some positive non-zero value while the tail $f - f_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: It's best to think of $\{ nx\}$ as rotation by $x$ on a circle of length $1$. Then observe that $x$ is rational if and only if this rotation is periodic, and that if $x$ is indeed rational and $N$ is given, then any neighborhood of $x$ contains points such that $ny$ is very close to $nx$ for $1\le n\le N$, and each time $nx$ visits zero, $ny$  is just below zero.

Comment: @r9m, Can you show your hint more in details please?

Comment: @ChristianRemling That draws a very nice intuition for the discontinuity at rationals. Maybe elaborate it as an answer? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f_n(x) := \{nx\}$ is a periodic function of period $1/n$. It's only discontinuity are at the rational points $\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{Z} := \left\{\frac{p}{n}: p \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$. In particular by periodicity we have $$J_{f_n}(p/n) = \lim\limits_{x \to \frac{p}{n}^{+}} f_n(x) - \lim\limits_{x \to \frac{p}{n}^{-}} f_n(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to 0^{+}} f_n(x) - \lim\limits_{x \to 0^{-}} f_n(x) = -1.$$ Now note that for a point $x = p/q$ with $(p,q) = 1$ this jump discontinuity occurs only for functions $f_{kq}$ where, $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Since the convergence of $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^2}f_n \to f$ is uniform on $\mathbb{R}$ (by [Weierstrass $M$-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) for example) we get $$J_f(p/q) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}J_{f_n}(p/q) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(kq)^2}J_{f_{kq}}(p/q) = -\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(kq)^2}.$$

On the other hand if $x \not\in \mathbb{Q}$ then $f_n$ is continuous at $x$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, which proves the continuity of $f$ at $x$ by uniform convergence.

Comment: But what about $f(x)$ in irrational points?

Comment: Ah! That's much easier. Can you show that $f_N(x)$ is continuous at irrationals? then the conclusion will follow from uniform convergence of $f_N \to f$.

Comment: I know that it's follows from uniform convergence. Sorry but I can't show rigorously why $f_N(x)$ is continuous at irrationals. Can you prove it please?

Comment: The statement "$nx\notin N$, in which case for any positive $\epsilon$-nbd of the point $x$, where, $0<\epsilon<\frac{1}{n}$, $\left\{\frac{np}{q}\pm n\epsilon\right\} = \left\{\frac{np}{q}\right\} \pm n\epsilon$" is false: consider $\frac{p}{q}=\frac{1}{10}$, $n=53$, and $\epsilon=\frac{7}{530}$; then $\{\frac{np}{q}-n\epsilon\}=\{5.3-0.7\}=\{4.6\}=0.6\neq \{5.3\}\pm 0.7= \left\{\frac{np}{q}\right\} \pm n\epsilon$.

Comment: @r9m I actually managed to prove it using your previous approach-that logical error did not invalidate the whole proof.

Comment: @r9m you are correct-I was wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134215/discussion-between-dick-grayson-and-r9m).

Answer (score -1):

Start with $x = a$ and conclude that $f(x) = f(a)$.  What if we are not sure of the value of $x$.  Is it true that $x \approx a$ implies $f(x) \approx f(a)$.  This is the basis of our concept of "continuity" - often we are able to guess the value of a function based on "nearby" or "similar values".

Continuous functions behave nicely under limits: $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$

Let's use this definition to try to check your function is continuous for irrational $x \not \in \mathbb{Q}$ such as $x = \sqrt{\color{#0055FF}{2}}, \sqrt{3}$.  If I just write out the equations.

$$ \lim_{x \to \sqrt{\color{#0055FF}{2}}}\; \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\{nx\}}{n^2} \stackrel{?}{=} \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\{n \sqrt{\color{#0055FF}{2}}\}}{n^2} $$

I have no idea about the number on the right side.  Is it even finite?  It's smaller than another number I am familiar with.  Even if the function is discontinuous or not, at east point it has a finite value.

$$ \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ \{ n \sqrt{2}\}}{n^2} \leq \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ 1}{n^2}  = \frac{\pi^2}{6} < \infty $$

What about nearby points?  Can we show that for $x \approx \sqrt{2}$ this function attains close values?

$$ \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ \{ n (\sqrt{2} \pm \color{red}{\epsilon})\}}{n^2} \stackrel{?}{\approx}  \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ \{ n \sqrt{2} \}}{n^2} $$

Let $\epsilon \ll 1$ be a really small number.  How about $\epsilon = \frac{1}{1000}$ or $\frac{1}{M}$.  We can bound the error in one of two possible ways.

- $ \{ n \sqrt{2}  \} - n \epsilon < \{ n \sqrt{2} \pm \epsilon \} < \{ n \sqrt{2}  \} + n \epsilon$
- the error here is smaller than $\frac{1}{n^2} \times n \epsilon = \frac{\epsilon}{n} \leq \epsilon$

Jumping does not occur before the $M = \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ term. For $n > M$:  $ \displaystyle 0 \leq  \frac{ \{ n \sqrt{2} \pm \epsilon \}}{n^2} \leq \frac{1}{M^2} = \epsilon^2$.

It seems we have established uniform convergence in the terms of the series and therefore our limit is correct for $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$.

---

[image]

Here's the plot I found.

It certainly looks **discontinuous** at $x = \frac{1}{2}$ as we expected.  It looks like a kind of "swoosh" shape repeated many times,  but a similar jump discontinuity should appear at all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$.

It's a totally reasonable-looking function. It's defined at all points in $[0,1]$, $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx$ makes perfect sense and yet this function has horrible discontinuities everywhere!

Comment: Dear! Your proof is little bit hard to me. Can you explain it more in detail? Can you wrote it more rigorously please?

Comment: I can't understand how you prove it's continuity at irrationals

Comment: @RaheemNajib I am thinking about how to explain better.  Where did you find this?? Was this a textbook problem?

Comment: It's problem from PMA Rudin. Chapter 7, Problem 10. I am thinking about this problem more than 3 days but any results. I would be very grateful if you'll help me

Comment: This is not even wrong! It is simply meaningless!

Comment: @AlexM. could you point to something particular that you disagree with? what is meaningless about a numerical computation?  $x = \sqrt{2}$ could be any arbitrary irrational.